# What are the 'Download Tests' and how can I get one?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In the Battle Test, there are three options on the first menu.

1. Try a Battle Test
2. Try a Download Test
3. Download Tests

What does 2 and 3 mean? When ever I click on 2, it tells me that I should download some Battle Tests. I then go to 3, and select Internet, which tells me data could not be found.

What are download tests, and how do I download some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it is an unused feature. That is to say, no downloadable tests were ever released for either Pokemon X & Y, or Omega Ruby & Alpha Sapphire.

I remember not being able to download tests when I played, and I cannot find any mention online of specific downloadable tests, or any special events that may have featured them. Serebii has the following on the X/Y Battle Institute page:

> There is also a download option which will allow for the download of special training scenarios through the Nintendo Network, and locally, but it is unknown whether or not this shall be utilised as a feature.
>   <sub>Serebii.Net - [Pokemon X & Y - Battle Institute](https://www.serebii.net/xy/battleinstitute.shtml) - Retrieved 21 October 2019</sub>

And a similar message (without the final sentence) is on the Omega Ruby & Alpha Sapphire page:

> There is also a download option which will allow for the download of special training scenarios through the Nintendo Network, and locally..
>   <sub>Serebii.Net - [Pokemon Omega Ruby Alpha Sapphire - Battle Institute](https://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/battleinstitute.shtml) - Retrieved 21 October 2019</sub>

The rest of the more common sources of info surrounding the battle institute either simply mention it as a feature without elaboration, or don't mention it at all, as is the case with Bulbapedia's entry on the [Battle Institute](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Institute). One thread on [GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67887908) simply states that there are 'no download tests yet'.

Furthermore, there doesn't seem to be any rom-hacking/modding scene that has investigated the 'download test' functionality to either add tests or alter game data.

Suffice to say it's a bit of dead functionality that never got used.

Comment: If anyone is in the romhacking/modding scene and has some further info surrounding investigations into the download test system that I wasn't able to glean, please share!

Answer (score -1):

Apparently there never were any tests to download, it's just stupid honestly!

Comment: Got a source for this?